# add view to scrollview in android

Tags: android, view, scrollview, gif, ondraw

I have a relative layout inside a scrollview, then i created a new view with this code:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(5, 5, 140, 140, paint);

    }
}
```

Then i try to use layout.addView(DrawView) to add the new view to the relative layout, so it can be scrollable with the rest of the content, but is doesn't work, nothing shows up..

Am i missing something ?

Edit:

```
DrawView formas;
GifMovieView gif;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    final ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    //gif = new GifMovieView(this, t_img);
    formas = new DrawView(this);

    layout.addView(formas);
    scrollView.addView(layout);


    this.setContentView(scrollView);    
    inicializar();
    load(layout);   
}
```

Comment: I think you missed `super.onDraw(canvas);`.

Comment: Can you show the `addView` code, please? I suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: i tried adding that and it is the same.. but thanks !

Comment: updated the first post !
I don't know if it is that simple.. i just started learning so sorry if i'm doing some big stupid mistake !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to override `onMeasure()` in your DrawView. Otherwise your view will have size of 0x0 pixels.

You can start with something as simple as

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
}
```

just to prove it works, but you will need to do some more meaningful, based on what are contents of your view.

Start from [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) to see help on overriding `onDraw()` and `onMeasure()`

Comment: IT WORKED ! i just have to adjust the measures now ! thank you !